# Group by number of occuring values

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table `Customers` and a table `Customercards`. A customer can have multiple customercards. The table `Customercards` references the customer with customer_id.

I would like to write a query which counts the customercards per customer and prints out the result, grouped by the count of cards, like this:

```
cards  count
0      50       
1      37
2      13
3      5
4      1
```

Currently I have a query which counts the customers with a given count of cards using `group by` and `having`. But I have to use this query multiple times to count the different amounts of customercards. Example:

```
SELECT c.customer_id
FROM CUSTOMERS c JOIN CUSTOMERCARDS cc ON c.customer_id = cc.customer_id
group by c.customer_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

Is there a way to put this into one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I call this a "histogram of histograms" query.  You can use two aggregations:

```
SELECT cnt, COUNT(*), MIN(customer_id), MAX(customer_id)
FROM (SELECT c.customer_id, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM CUSTOMERS c JOIN
           CUSTOMERCARDS cc
           ON c.customer_id = cc.customer_id
      GROUP BY c.customer_id
     ) c
GROUP BY cnt
ORDER BY cnt;
```

I include the minimum and maximum customer ids, just because I find it use to have examples when I do such a query.

Note:  You don't actually need the `JOIN`, so you can simplify this to:

```
SELECT cnt, COUNT(*), MIN(customer_id), MAX(customer_id)
FROM (SELECT cc.customer_id, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM CUSTOMERCARDS cc
      GROUP BY cc.customer_id
     ) c
GROUP BY cnt
ORDER BY cnt;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I got confused working with those two group by clauses. Now it is working :)